# Why did the authors of `pd.var()` choose a default of `ddof=1` compared to `np.var()` whose default `ddof=0`?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Source

- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.var.html
- https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html

I understand the choice of degrees of freedom relates to the decision to model your variance calculation for sample or population variances (http://www.differencebetween.net/science/mathematics-statistics/difference-between-sample-variance-population-variance/).

What I don't understand is why did pandas choose their default when it would have been less of a gotcha to inherit numpy's defaults. Anyone can explain why?

Comment: I think of pandas as a real world data, time series and such, tool.  So the default that's correct for samples makes sense.  numpy is more of a 'pure' numerical tool. It might be used to model a population.  Maybe it's safer to expect that its users will know when  to use the nondefault alternative.

Comment: Also on SO pandas new comers seem to have even less knowledge of numpy.

Answer (score 3):

I would actually ask why did numpy choose `ddof=0` for the default.  The `n-1` in the denominator is called the Bessel correction and is generally used for 1D sample variance.  I was actually surprised that Numpy has is as `n`.

There is a good discussion on it here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406327/degrees-of-freedom-in-sample-variance

Comment: Oh that's an interesting link! Thanks for sharing.